# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Retrieving the selected value from a dropdownlist and a listbox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I'm using the example outlined in Steven Sanderson's book to create a multi-page, wizard like form for a web application.

(See http://books.google.com/books?id=lfPkn31fpNQC&pg=PA477#v=onepage&q&f=false for the exact example).

I have it working to the point where I can persist data across pages, but I have no idea how to do this for a DropDownList control or a ListBox control.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know how to use dropDownList box in mvc?

Comment: I have a DDL created on my UI - but I want to know how I can persist this information across a wizard like, multi-page form. See the link in my question for more information. In this example, he's using some textbox controls and persisting this information across many pages using hidden fields - I want to be able to do the same with a DDL on my UI and also a ListBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply the dropdown list is an HTML select control, it's value will be in the form values posted to the action so if you set your form to post to an action then in the aciton you need:

```
public ActionResult RecieveForm(FormCollection values)
{
   var dropdownSelectedvalue = values["nameofdropdown"];
   ...
   work with result
   ...
   return View()
}
```

Comment: OK, so that's how I would get the values in my controller. But, like the example in the link in my question, I have a 'confirm' page - how can I determine the selected values and display them in the 'confirm' view?

Comment: You would need to pass the selected value you received on the post to the view and when initialising the dropdown on the confirm page, add this value as the selected value to the SelectList. It takes a while to get the MVC concept after working with Viewstate controls before :-)